# How to update a table with values from another table based on different conditions

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables (as the following), I need to update table1's columns with Table2's values based on what language it is in table2.

Something like this (but its not valid syntax):

```
UPDATE Table1
If table2.language='EN'
  SET description_EN = Table2.Description
Else 
  SET description_FR=table2.description 
FROM table1
left outer join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```

Table1:

```
id  description_EN  Description_FR
1   null            null
2   null            null
3   null            null
```

Table 2:

```
id  Language    Description
1   EN          description in English 1
1   FR          description in French 1
2   EN          description in English 2
2   FR          description in French 2
3   EN          description in English 3
3   FR          description in French 3
```

Comment: The syntax is `UPDATE ... FROM ... WHERE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` with each column, returning the joined description if the language matches, or self (ie no change) if not the correct language:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET
description_EN = CASE WHEN table2.language = 'EN' THEN Table2.Description else description_EN END,
description_FR = CASE WHEN table2.language = 'FR' THEN Table2.Description else description_FR END
FROM table1
JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

This joins every language to the row, but only makes a change when appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. It was really helpful, I do see results coming in to both columns. id Description_En Description_FR
1 description in English 1 
2  description in French 2
3 description in English 3

Comment: @lisa so, does it work? I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me in the last part of your comment.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't allow me to edit just now... Thank you. It was really helpful. Both 'Description_EN' and  'Description_EN' columns have values coming in. But not all values were brought in from Table 2 to table 1. I queried to see if there any records in Table2's 'Language' column that has value other than 'EN' or 'FR', I have none. So there shouldn't be any empty records in the newly updated table1 description_XX columns. I am puzzled, any ideas maybe why?

Comment: @lisa  are there multiple entries in table2 for a given id and language, with one entry having a null description?

Comment: @lisa can you provide all data for an id that has the problem? (Don't need full description though - "foo" will do)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `CASE` statement:

```
Update      T1
Set         description_EN = Case When T2.Language = 'EN'   
                Then T2.Description 
                Else T1.description_EN 
            End,
            description_FR = Case When T2.Language <> 'EN'  
                Then T2.Description 
                Else T1.description_FR 
            End 
From        Table1  T1
Left Join   Table2  T2  On  T1.Id = T2.Id
```

This will check to see if the `Language` is `EN` and update that value, otherwise, it will set it equal to itself.

Likewise for the `FR` one.

Comment: Why do we need `Left Join`.

Comment: @Prdp Heck if I know, I'm just copying his `JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you. It was really helpful. Both 'Description_EN' and  'Description_EN' columns have values coming in. But not all values were brought in from Table 2 to table 1. I queried the tables to see if there any records in Table1's 'Language' column that has value other than 'EN' or 'FR', I have none. So there shouldn't be any empty records in table2. I am puzzled, any ideas maybe why?